# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tls_client'

Tags: github, tls1.2, modulenotfounderror, nomodule

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\brave\OperaGX-Promo-Gen-main\OperaGX-Promo-Gen-main\gen.py", line 11, in 
import tls_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tls_client'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\brave\OperaGX-Promo-Gen-main\OperaGX-Promo-Gen-main\gen.py", line 17, in 
import tls_client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tls_client'

D:\brave\OperaGX-Promo-Gen-main\OperaGX-Promo-Gen-main>
`
getting this error
already tried uninstalling and installing still no fix
any fix?

reinstalling, with --user aswell

Answer (score 0):

pip install tsl_client (run python gen.py and not py gen.py if ur doing that)